# Download image in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have an image download link, How can I download it in Nodejs? I don't want to store it in file system, I want to store it in database.

Comment: You want to store an image in a db?

Comment: @frankenapps Yes, mongodb

Comment: Do you plan to use something like GridFS?

Comment: @frankenapps No my images are pretty small, under 100kb.